# Increase internal memory of Samsung J2 prime

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage

I bought Samsung J2 prime phone. Some details of that phone as follows.

Model - SM -G532G

Android version - 6.0.1

I heard that earlier it came with good feature that allow us to format external SD card as internal storage.

I tried to format my new SD card as internal storage. But it does not give that option in my phone.

Is there anyone who has similar experience to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK adaptive storage for some Samsung models are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the sd card as ext2, default sd card storage type is fat32 i think?, the android may not recognize it as a usable sd card, now a notification may appear saying : (SD CARD NAME) is not recognizable, it need to format or something close to that, a option may appear: Format as INTERNAL STORAGE and Format as PORTABLE STORAGE, pick the "Format as INTERNAL STORAGE"

EDIT: I think your android was flashed because of bootloops, i dunno?, It remove the option to format as internal storage

Comment: It only show "Format as PORTABLE STORAGE" option.

Comment: I formatted it in ubuntu using gparted.

Comment: Hmm, strange i have phone that have a 6.0,  it gives me an option that i can format as internal storage, well your phone doesn't support it

Comment: I found this article which gives steps to fix this problem. Do you have any idea on this? https://www.techinvade.com/fix-bricked-samsung-galaxy-j2-prime-unroot-stock-rom/#_Fixing_BootLoop_Problem_In_Samsung_Galaxy_J2_Prime_After_Flashing_Stock_ROMFirmware .  Still I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Hey is the problem is now solved? if no i've watch some dude enabling it using ADB it might be helpful to you or others, here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8j6j__0jxs